# SwiftUI NavigationStack duplicate view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

Im trying to use new functionality of navigation in SwiftUI and now I've problem with similar early problem in NavigationLink when destination view created more than twice. Could you please help me to find right solution.

```
enum Step: String, Identifiable {
    case page1
    case page2
    case page3
    
    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}
class Router: ObservableObject {
    @Published var steps: [Step] = []
    static let shared = Router()
    private init(){}
    func showPage1() {
        steps.append(.page1)
    }
    
    func showPage2() {
        steps.append(.page2)
    }
    
    func showPage3() {
        steps.append(.page3)
    }
    
    func popToRoot() {
        steps.removeAll()
    }
}

class BaseStepViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let step: Step
    let router: Router
    init(step: Step, router: Router) {
        self.step = step
        self.router = router
        print("Created step \(step.rawValue)")
    }
    
    func shopNextPage() {
        router.showPage2()
    }
}

class Step1ViewModel: BaseStepViewModel { }

class Step2ViewModel: BaseStepViewModel {
    override func shopNextPage() {
        router.showPage3()
    }
}

class Step3ViewModel: BaseStepViewModel {
    override func shopNextPage() {
        router.popToRoot()
    }
}


struct StepView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: BaseStepViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            viewModel.shopNextPage()
        } label: {
            Text(viewModel.step.rawValue)
        }

    }
}

class WelcomeViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let router: Router
    var id: String {
        title
    }
    
    init(title: String, router: Router) {
        self.title = title
        self.router = router
        print("Created welcome view")
    }
    
    func startFlow() {
        router.showPage1()
    }
}

struct WelcomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: WelcomeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            viewModel.startFlow()
        } label: {
            Text(viewModel.title)
        }

    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    
    @StateObject var router = Router.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.steps) {
            WelcomeView(viewModel: .init(title: "Welcome", router: router))
                    .id("Welcome")
            .navigationDestination(for: Step.self) { step in
                switch step {
                case .page1:
                    StepView(viewModel: Step1ViewModel(step: step, router: router))
                case .page2:
                    StepView(viewModel: Step2ViewModel(step: step, router: router))
                case .page3:
                    StepView(viewModel: Step3ViewModel(step: step, router: router))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the WelcomeViewModel created multiple times. I'm tried add a specific id to make view/viewModel unique, but it's didn't help.

Comment: SwiftUI is quite different from UIKit, so best treat them in their own respective ways. Don't be alarmed by the creation of view multiple times, View is treated more like a view configuration, it would be created when the parent state changes. Don't worry about that. It doesn't mean that the underlying view is created multiple times, SwiftUI is smart with managing the differences and re-rendering only when necessary

Comment: The second view is visible on device when steps changed.

Comment: I added a print in WelcomeView init and it called twice

Comment: I have added an answer see if it fixes your problem, the part that tripped me was your print statement which was `print("Created welcome view")` instead of `print("Created welcome view model")`

Comment: As mentioned, SwiftUI is not UIKit. Looking at your code, it is evident to me, that you need to understand the **very basics of SwiftUI** before going 
on to code your App.
Do for example, the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/   
Also I strongly suggest, you have a look at this link, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app :

Answer (score 0):

## Approach:

- When you are passing a StateObject from outside initialise it using `StateObject(wrappedValue:)` as shown below.

## Code:

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: WelcomeViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: WelcomeViewModel) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            viewModel.startFlow()
        } label: {
            Text(viewModel.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I have changed print to "Created welcome viewModel" and now output is: 
Created welcome viewModel
Created welcome viewModel
Created step page1
Created welcome viewModel
Created step page2

Comment: I can send you zip file with project if you want

Comment: Did you try my solution above? `_viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)`

Comment: Yes I’m tried but it’s didn’t help